# Not Able to depoly and run application on windows Phone 8.1 device with VS 2012 Exp for WP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

When i try to run app in windows phone 8.1 , i am getting following error . I am using Visual studio 2012 Express for WP

> **A specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another** **application.**

[image]

I have tried following things but none worked

- Reset Phone
- App Data Remove
- Deploy Project
- Repair the visual Studio
- Close all other apps and restart PC

What could be the issue ? I am using **Micromax Win121** device having `windows phone 8.1` OS

Please let me know if you need any more information for this

Comment: possible duplicate of ["A specified communication resources(port) is already in use" when attaching the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088599/a-specified-communication-resourcesport-is-already-in-use-when-attaching-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue once. This [Blog](http://blog.masterdevs.com/a-specified-communication-resource-port-is-already-in-use-by-another-application/) rectifies the issue for me.

[image]

And make sure you are not debugging same device(whether it is emulator also) on any other visual studio. In other words you can run at a time one device only from visual studios.

Still you didn't rectify the problem try these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088599/a-specified-communication-resourcesport-is-already-in-use-when-attaching-the)

Hope this Helps