# Is the Windows 10 supports the WindowsPhoneSilverlight 8 , 8.1 applications

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-10

I have developed the APP in WindowsPhoneSilverlight 8.1 as well as 8 and the APP not runs in Windows 10. Any one suggest an idea to how to run this,

Is the Windows 10 supports the WindowsPhoneSilverlight 8 , 8.1 applications.

Thanks in advance.

Elavarasan M

Comment: Windows 8/8.1 apps are supported in Windows 10. Can you tell me what is the actual problem? What error do you have? Are you running your app in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: I have run the app in emulator.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Port is already in use like that.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gabe Aul has stated](https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/567706835038126080) that Windows 10 will support Silverlight Applications.**

It should be noted that Silverlight will be deprecated in Edge, however. The Edge team goes into detail as to why they are deprecating support [in this blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/), as [well as this one.](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/02/moving-to-html5-premium-media/)

**But really what it comes down to is Interoperability on the web.**

Some of the more notable removals are those where Microsoft Edge supports the latest standard API definition and removes support for MS prefixed versions of the APIs. Examples include CSS Transforms, Fullscreen API, and Pointer Events. This brings up an important topic: vendor prefixes. You’ll see a trend in the vendor prefixes in Microsoft Edge compared to IE:

Our support (or lack thereof) of prefixed APIs is data-driven with compatibility as the sole purpose for any that remain. As examples, -webkit-border-radius is still in use on over 60% of page loads and the MS-prefixed Encrypted Media Extensions APIs are still in use on top video streaming services. Because of the impact on interoperability across the Web, these are supported in Microsoft Edge for the time being.

The consensus across the industry is that vendor prefixes cause more harm than good and the necessity of browsers supporting other vendor’s prefixes is a good example of why. Going forward, we’re using feature flags (accessible by navigating to about:flags) to introduce experimental APIs and minting new vendor prefixed APIs sparingly, if ever. Today, you’ll find examples like early implementations of CSS Filters, Touch Events, and HTML5 date inputs in about:flags.

We’re also working with other browser vendors on exploring new approaches to experimental APIs that enable easier and broader access to experimental APIs while minimizing the compatibility burden that prefixes incur. Check out this talk (starts around 31 min mark) for an initial proposal we’ve made, tentatively named “API Trials”.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you: ["A specified communication resources(port) is already in use" when attaching the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088599/a-specified-communication-resourcesport-is-already-in-use-when-attaching-the)
Try updating Visual Studio and the emulators.