# How to solve DEP6500 and DEP6701 errors?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, uwp-xaml

I have a project called **BTLE** in its own solution. Loading the project and running it with the debugger on the phone works find.

I have a second solution that Loads and compile fine as well.

I added the **BTLE** project (Add/Existing Project) to the second solution, compiled it and tried to run it in the debugger.

I can see the application was loaded fine to the phone (I can run it from the phone), but the debugger will not start and I am getting the following error messages:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: BTLE, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
1>Updating the layout...
1>Copying files: Total 2 mb to layout...
1>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
1>Registering the application to run from layout...
1>Deployment complete (0:00:05.469). Full package name: "76081875-4de1-4857-    8ce6-4e7a580ee1b6_1.0.0.0_arm__fdr7mxj3cnxqw"
2>------ Deploy started: Project: STPWindows, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>DEP6500 : A specified communication resource (port) is already in use by  another application. 0x89731800: 
2>DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'DEP6500 : A   specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another    application. 0x89731800: '.
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea why I am getting these error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088599/a-specified-communication-resourcesport-is-already-in-use-when-attaching-the

Comment: No. I saw the other one. It is from 4 years ago and the solution there isn't relevant here.
thx though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not mention if your multiple project solutions have multiple startups.

See screenshot below.

[image]

Under Action, Change the relative actions of each projects and try deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the last answer in ["A specified communication resources(port) is already in use" when attaching the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088599/a-specified-communication-resourcesport-is-already-in-use-when-attaching-the) and the fact that you first deployed BTLE and afterwards deployed a project containing BTLE. I don't think you can easily put the same Module (with the same ID) twice into Windows Phone and then debug it. I don't even know, if there is a public writeable GAC in Windows Phone to avoid this effect. 
Would you try to change the Project GUID (Project Setting->Application->Assembly Info) of your BTLE Project for your second solution? Or remove the first BTLE Project from the phone (and maybe reboot)?