# dep6500 errors on multi-app deploys

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

I'm receiving an error that's nearly identical to what's posted in [How to solve DEP6500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928281/how-to-solve-dep6500-and-dep6701-errors) while deploying a solution with multiple projects to an emulator or Lumia 950xl:

The issue isn't resolved and I've got further detail to add here in the hope that it might resolve & clarify both questions (that question is presently the top hit when I search for DEP6500)

AFAICT, mine really appears to be a VS15 solution deployment configuration issue.

I have a single solution with five projects: three apps, a class library, and a win runtime component:

1. First trivial app, references #2
2. Universal class library, references no other project directly, but attempts to use an AppServiceConnection to connect to #4
3. Second trivial app, just a hello world, references absolutely nothing
4. Third trivial app, references #5, meant to be used via an AppServiceConnection
5. Universal windows runtime component, references nothing

Really, what I want to be able to do is start with nothing deployed to the device, select "Deploy Solution", and have all three apps successfully deployed.

Based on the rest of the description below, I'm clearly misconfiguring this solution, but for the life of me I don't see where.

At the solution level, if I configure any combination of two or more of the three apps to deploy, I get the DEP6500 error when I try "Deploy Solution" - actually, two DEP6500 errors when three apps are configured to deploy.

If I configure **only one** of the three apps to deploy, deploying the solution works just fine.

If I uninstall every deployed app and deploy just #1, as you might expect, it has trouble at runtime when it tries to use #4.

If, instead, I deploy just #1 and then deploy just #4, #1 runs just fine.
As I said earlier, if #1 and #4 are both configured to deploy, deploying the whole solution fails.

The third app, #3, is really uninvolved in this whole mess, I only added it to better characterize the problems deploying #1 and #4.

Seeing as each deploys just fine individually and all three can be deployed to my device at the same time if I deploy them one at at time, how can I configure Visual Studio 15 to deploy all three when I run "Deploy Solution"?

Finally, it would help to find out what type of port the IDE referring to when I produces the error in question:

DEP6500 : A   specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another    application. 0x89731800

helpful smaller questions may be: that is that port used for? when is it opened? how long is it open? how can I configure VS15 in a way that avoids port collisions between apps during full-solution deploys?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that Visual Studio 15 just doesn't appear to be able to time the deployment correctly when you ask it to do a full deploy of every project in one action.

In this case, manually deploying each project one at a time yields a good result.

I suspect the "port" in question has to do with device deployment, as I can do a full deploy to my local machine without issue but see the DEP6500 error on deploys to my Lumia 950XL.

My aim was to be able to do a full deploy from a single VS15 menu option and that's still not technically working consistently, but I suppose I've found a workaround in as much as a piecemeal manual deploy is working everywhere.